# Show $|\partial_{x_i}\Phi(x,t)| \leq \frac{M_2}{\sqrt{t}}\Phi(x,2t)$, and $|\partial_{x_ix_j}\Phi(x,t)|\leq \frac{M_3}{t}\Phi(x,2t)$

Tags: calculus, inequality

> Recall that If $0<\alpha<1$, $0\leq \beta$, then there exists
>       $M(\alpha,\beta)>0$ so that  $$z^\beta e^{-z}\leq Me^{-\alpha z}$$
>       for all $z\geq 0$.   Show $|\partial_t\Phi(x,t)| \leq \dfrac{M_1}{t}\Phi(x,2t)$, $|\partial_{x_i}\Phi(x,t)| \leq
>  \dfrac{M_2}{\sqrt{t}}\Phi(x,2t)$, and
>   $|\partial_{x_ix_j}\Phi(x,t)|\leq \dfrac{M_3}{t}\Phi(x,2t)$

**Proof:** Recall that $\Phi(x,t)=\dfrac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}}\exp\left[-\dfrac{|x|^2}{4t}\right]$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $t>0$.

First, we will show that $|\partial_t\Phi(x,t)|\leq \dfrac{M_1}{t}\cdot \Phi(x,2t)$. By some calculus and part (a),
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
|\partial_t\Phi(x,t)|
& = \left| \dfrac{1}{(4\pi)^{n/2}}\cdot \dfrac{-n}{2}t^{-(n+2)/2} \exp\left[-\dfrac{|x|^2}{4t}\right] 
+ \dfrac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}} \exp\left[-\dfrac{|x|^2}{4t}\right] \cdot \dfrac{|x|^2}{4t^2}\right| \\
& = \dfrac{1}{2t(4\pi t)^{n/2}} \exp\left[-\dfrac{|x|^2}{4t}\right] \cdot \left| -n  + \dfrac{|x|^2}{2t}\right| \\
& = \dfrac{1}{t}\cdot \dfrac{1}{(8\pi t)^{n/2}} \exp\left[-\dfrac{|x|^2}{4t}\right] \cdot \left| -n  + \dfrac{|x|^2}{2t}\right| \\
& \leq \dfrac{1}{t}\cdot \dfrac{1}{(8\pi t)^{n/2}} \exp\left[-\dfrac{|x|^2}{8t}\right] \cdot M_1 \\
& = \dfrac{M_1}{t}\cdot \Phi(x,2t) 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
with $\alpha=1/2$ and $M_1=\left| -n  + \dfrac{|x|^2}{2t}\right|>0$.

Next, we will show that $|\partial_{x_i}\Phi(x,t)| \leq \dfrac{M_2}{\sqrt{t}}\Phi(x,2t)$. By some calculus and part (a),
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
|\partial_{x_i}\Phi(x,t)|
& = \left| \dfrac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}} \exp\left[-\dfrac{|x|^2}{4t}\right] \cdot -\dfrac{2|x|}{4t} \right| \\
& = \dfrac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}} \exp\left[-\dfrac{|x|^2}{4t}\right] \cdot \dfrac{|x|}{2t} \\
& = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \cdot \dfrac{1}{(8\pi t)^{n/2}} \exp\left[-\dfrac{|x|^2}{4t}\right] \cdot \dfrac{|x|}{\sqrt{t}} \\
& \leq \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \cdot \dfrac{1}{(8\pi t)^{n/2}} \exp\left[-\dfrac{|x|^2}{8t}\right] \cdot M_2 \\
& = \dfrac{M_2}{\sqrt{t}}\Phi(x,2t)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
with $\alpha=1/2$ and $M_2=\dfrac{|x|}{\sqrt{t}}>0$.

**I know that my derivative of $|x|$ is wrong what is it suppose to be?**

**Also for the third inequality, do I just take the derivative twice?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partial derivative you want is
$$\frac{\partial |x|^2}{\partial x_i}=2x_i.$$
You just need the inequality $|x_i|\le|x|$.

For the second order partial derivative,
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i\partial x_j} \exp\left(-\dfrac{|x|^2}{4t}\right)=\frac{e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}}}{2t}\Big(\frac{x_ix_j}{2t}-\delta_{i,j}\Big),$$
where $\delta_{i,j}$ is the Kronecker delta function.
Here you need the inequality 
$$2x_ix_j\le x_i^2+x_j^2\le |x|^2$$
to furnish your final inequality.

Your characterization of the $M_i$ is wrong. They are constants, independent of $(t,x)$.